# Determine the moment of completion of asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a json data which contains hrefs. Each href provides another json data etc. I have a recursive function which processes json data. When this processing finishes I need to do another actions. How can I detect this moment? All requests with href are asynchronous and I don't know how many hrefs may exist.
For resolving href and getting json data I use fetch.

Comment: post your code, I can already say you need to use Promise

Comment: `I use fetch` well, that makes it simple ... fetch returns a promise ... `Promise.all` can wait for a number of promises to resolve ... knowing those two things, the solution practically writes itself

Comment: I solved my problem using Promise.alll and array of async requests. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your recursive function you must already have a way to detect if there's more data coming.

```
if ( more_data )
    recursive_call();
```

So just add...

```
else
    do_other_actions();
```